# Linking to Another Report in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, report, builder, drillthrough

I have 2 reports at diffent report pages in Report Builder Server. First one which has my category values from sql database, another has invoice details about those categories.

How can i access to invoice details when i click a related category in first report categories?

Thanks.

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-drillthrough-action-on-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `Drill Through` report.

The most informative tutorial I have found is the [following 20 min video from Wise Owl Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qk8BWLwGPI&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcmEFHyxCRwA_gb29WOz5SJU&index=69). This will be able to explain it quicker and faster than typing it out here.
Recommend watching this series for any question you may have.